# Another question about Lambert Function

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, analysis

I am intrested in the real solutions of the equation:

$w(x)e^{-w(x)}=x$,

for $x\in(0,1/e)$. For the solution in $(0,1)$, there is a nice series defining its convergence to  $0$. My question is: is there a nice asymptotic formula even for the other, going to $\infty$? Is it something like:

$w(x)=-\log(x)+\log(-\log(x))+O(1)$

as $x\to 0$?

Comment: What about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Asymptotic_expansions and the references therein is unclear?

Comment: Well, the expansion you can find there is just for $x>e$, which does not apply in this situation. Moreover the expansion in $log(x)$, $log(log(x))$ has no references, and the one which are at a hand in the net are quite unclear. Beside this, I am really looking for an elementary proof. The bound $w(x)\geq -log(x)+log(-log(x))$ is quite elementar. Proving the estimate above is more tricky for me. That's what I am looking for.

Comment: I finally found what I was looking for, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/106482/lambert-w-1x-as-x-rightarrow-0-asymptotic-behavior